# ng-model functionality with bootstrap typeahead

Tags: angularjs

This is a rather strange question, but that's probably because I don't understand how this works.  Maybe someone can clarify for me.

Here's some code from angular bootstrap typeahead:

```
<input type="text" ng-model="customSelected" placeholder="Custom template" typeahead="state as state.name for state in statesWithFlags | filter:{name:$viewValue}" typeahead-template-url="customTemplate.html" class="form-control">
```

If I understand this correctly, when user types 'a' in the textfield, customSelected = 'a'.  When user types 'ab', customSelected is 'ab'.  When the user selects an item from the typeahead, customSelected becomes the object they selected (e.g., maybe something like {title:'abc', id:5})

Is my understanding correct?

If so, is it possible to set this typeahead a particular value?  e.g., say, I create a button.  When the user clicks the button, it is as if the user selected the first item in the typeahead.

I tried setting $scope.customSelected = statesWithFlags[0], but it didn't work...I don't think it works this way.

Any guidance would be appreciated.  Thanks!

Comment: What is array[0]? shouldn't it be statesWithFlags[0] that you assign to $scope.customSelected?

Comment: Yes, sorry.  Edited.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you stated, you have to initalize the model `customSelected` (you forgot $scope)

```
$scope.customSelected = $scope.statesWithFlags[ID];
```

Check this one: http://plnkr.co/edit/y25fqb?p=preview